# BibLaTeX – Remove Year Labels

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, miktex, apa-style

I started using BibLaTeX with the APA style, and I noticed that if two dates are the same (including *n.d.*), a label will be added to the year (e.g. *2016b* or *n.d.-b*). I would like to remove these.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{tutpnt1}

\cite{tutpnt2}

...

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

with `mwe.bib` containing:

```
@online{tutpnt1,
author = {{TutorialsPoint}},
title = {{SLDC -- Iterative Model}},
url = {http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sdlc/sdlc_iterative_model.htm},
date = {},
urldate = {2016-04-09}
}

@online{tutpnt2,
author = {{TutorialsPoint}},
title = {{SLDC -- V-Model}},
url = {http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sdlc/sdlc_v_model.htm},
date = {},
urldate = {2016-04-09}
}
```

Output with dates:
[image: Labels 'a' and 'b' added after years]

Output with no dates:
[image: Labels 'a' and 'b' added after entries with 'n.d.']

Is there any way to remove these labels? This assignment requires the APA style to be used. I am currently using MiKTeX v2.9.

Comment: But how can you then tell apart the two citations in the text? `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{extrayear}}\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{extrayear}}` I believe you will lose APA compliance if you apply these changes, `biblatex-apa` adheres to the APA rules quite strictly. BTW: It should probably only be `style=apa` in the `biblatex` options.

Comment: @moewe I don't know, but my teacher doesn't want them. The answer you gave me works, though.

Comment: Maybe you should ask your teacher what to do if you have two works from the same year by the same author.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get rid of the `extrayear` fields with

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{extradate}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{extradate}}
```

You will probably lose APA compliance that way and finding the right entry in the bibliography becomes a game of chance.

*edit* Updated for changes in `biblatex` v3.8 that renamed `extrayear` to `extradate`.

---

A slightly simpler way to get rid of `extradate` is by ignoring it when the data is read on the LaTeX side. To do that we redefine the field input handler with `\DeclareFieldInputHandler`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldInputHandler{extradate}{\def\NewValue{}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\nocite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to selectively get rid of the extrayear fields only when the year field is "n.d."?

Comment: @np8 Are you still using `bibatex-apa`? Anyway, I believe that warrants asking a new question (I haven't really checked, but it might be a bit more complicated than what I used here).

Comment: By `biblatex-apa` do you mean the `style` parameter? I have `bibstyle=authoryear` and `citestyle=numeric-comp`, but I have not used a `style` parameter.

Comment: @np8 Aha, would you mind posting a question with an MWE? Then I can have a look. (I just experimented with the styles you mention and did not see any "n.d.".)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they changed `extrayear` to `extradate`. So to update @moewe's answer:

```latex
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{extradate}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{extradate}}
```

https://github.com/CarlOrff/biblatex-archaeology/issues/7