# Any simple way to turnoff 'title' and 'pmid' field with biblatex?

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I am trying to use `biblatex` in `beamer` document class. There are some questions about [customizing `biblatex` style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) and using `biblatex` in `beamer`. But I feel I can not find a complete answer to my question and I am trying to find an easy way to achieve my goal with your help. I want the reference to be shown in the foot line of current frame with only some key fields. And I am approaching there. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Bringa2012_NL.12.3351,
    author    = {Bringa, E. M. and Monk, J. D. and Caro, A. and Misra, A. and Zepeda-Ruiz, L. and Duchaineau, M. and Abraham, F. and Nastasi, M. and Picraux, S. T. and Wang, Y. Q. and Farkas, D.},
    title     = {Are Nanoporous Materials Radiation Resistant?},
    journal   = {Nano Letters},
    year      = {2012},
    volume    = {12},
    number    = {7},
    pages     = {3351-3355},
    note      = {PMID: 21651306},
    doi       = {10.1021/nl201383u},
    eprint    = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/nl201383u},
    file      = {:Are Nanoporous Materials Radiation Resistant_Nano Lett., 2012 12 (7) pp 3351–3355.pdf:PDF},
    groups    = {Nanowire irradiation, simulation},
    owner     = {Wenqiang},
    timestamp = {2014.09.22},
    url       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/nl201383u},}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose,url=false,isbn=false,eprint=false,doi=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  biblatex test\footnote{\cite{Bringa2012_NL.12.3351}}
  biblatex test\footcite{Bringa2012_NL.12.3351}
  biblatex test\footfullcite{Bringa2012_NL.12.3351}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: The result]

However, two more modification needed. I can turnoff fields like `url`, `doi` etc. by using `url=false,isbn=false,eprint=false,doi=false`, but the 'PMID' and 'title' are still there and I found it hard to be modified. Is there any simple way like setting boolean values to turnoff these fields? And it is much better if the word `In:` can be turned off easily. I am using `\footnote`, `\footcite` and `\footfullcite` to get the same effect, if there any possible better method exists, please advise me.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title} \clearfield{note}} \renewbibmacro{in:}{}`. This could be tweaked for different entry types.  But this has to be a duplicate for both questions.

Comment: Thank you really very much! That is exactly what I want. I did not find a similar answer before, I am very sorry for that. Now, I got some thing like `E. M. Bringa et al. Nano Letters 12.7 (2012), pp.3351-3355`. I still want one minor change. Could please tell me is that possible to get rid of `,` and `pp` before the page numbers?

Comment: Comma: `\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addspace}`; 'pp.': `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}`. (Note that these can have pretty global effects.)

Comment: @jon Would you like to turn your comments into an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments

Comment: @samcarter -- Does that mean it shouldn't be answered? I am happy to answer it, but I assumed (without looking as I am rather pressed for time these days) that each of the parts of this question have been answered before.

Comment: @jon If you would like to add an answer, the question can easily be reopened.

Comment: Duplicate for http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303387/8528 (usage of `\AtEveryCitekey`). Duplicate for http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10686/8528 (removing `in:` from citations).

Comment: Duplicate for http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300985/8528 (changing `postnote` and `\bibpagespunct`).

Comment: @samcarter -- there are many candidates for these questions, but I think these three cover the four suggestions I made.

Comment: @jon Do you have any suggestion what to do with the question now it is reopened? Do you have any 'favourite' among the duplicates you found, or do you just want to give your comment as an official answer below?

Comment: @moewe -- I added an answer so it is taken off the list. Everyone should feel free to edit the answer if they have something to add or amend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Four changes are requested in the question. These have been answered before (probably more than once in some cases).

1. Remove the title and note fields in citations. One solution is to use:

   ```
   \AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title} \clearfield{note}}
   ```

   See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303387/8528 for more information.
2. Remove the 'in:' in citations. One solution is to do:

   ```
   \renewbibmacro{in:}{}
   ```

   See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10686/8528 for more information
3. (a) Modifying the `postnote` field so it doesn't print a comma and (b) inhibit the appearance of `pp.`. One solution is to do:

   ```
   \renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addspace}% remove comma
   \DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}%         not print p./pp.
   ```

   See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300985/8528 for more information.

Comment: CW because not an original answer, and because people can substitute better links if they know/find them.

Comment: I found a problem that `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{language}}` seems can not turnoff the field `language` in bibliography items. I think it is closely related to my previous question. Should I modify my original question above or open a new one? Please advise me. Thanks very much!

Comment: Best to ask a new question and link back to this question if need be.