# How to turnoff 'language' field with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I asked for help about method to turnoff some fields when use `biblatex`. It works well and [the original question can be seen here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341785/any-simple-way-to-turnoff-title-and-pmid-field-with-biblatex/343378?noredirect=1#comment859083_343378)
However, when I tried to use `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{language}}` to turnoff `language` field in bibliography items. It seems does not work. And my code is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{demo.bib}
@Article{Kubota2007_JoCMD.14.367,
author    = {Kubota, Alison and Wolfer, WilhelmG. and Valone, StevenM. and Baskes, MichaelI.},
title     = {Collision cascades in pure $\updelta$-plutonium},
journal   = {Journal of Computer-Aided Materials Design},
year      = {2007},
volume    = {14},
number    = {3},
pages     = {367-378},
month     = {oct},
doi       = {10.1007/s10820-007-9057-x},
file      = {:Collision cascades in pure delta-plutonium_J Computer-Aided Mater Des 14 (2007) 367–378.pdf:PDF},
groups    = {Unsorted},
issn      = {0928-1045},
keywords  = {Molecular dynamics; Radiation damage; Plutonium},
language  = {English},
owner     = {Wenqiang},
publisher = {Springer Netherlands},
review    = {Wigner-Seitz analysis},
timestamp = {2015.03.04},
url       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10820-007-9057-x},
}
@Article{Stukowski2012_MaSiMSaE.20.45021,
author        = {Stukowski, Alexander},
title         = {Structure identification methods for atomistic simulations of crystalline materials},
journal       = {Modelling and Simulation in Materials Science and Engineering},
year          = {2012},
volume        = {20},
number        = {4},
pages         = {045021},
__markedentry = {[Wenqiang:6]},
doi           = {10.1088/0965-0393/20/4/045021},
file          = {:Structure identification methods for atomistic simulations of crystalline materials_Modell. Simul. Mater. Sci. Eng. 20 (2012) 045021.pdf:PDF},
groups        = {Post-analysis},
issn          = {0965-0393},
language      = {en},
owner         = {Wenqiang},
review        = {adaptive CNA, common neighbor analysis modifier in OVITO},
timestamp     = {2016.11.06},
url           = {http://stacks.iop.org/0965-0393/20/i=4/a=045021},
urldate       = {2016-11-06},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,hyperref=true,style=nature,isbn=false,doi=false,eprint=false,url=false,maxbibnames=1]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{note} \clearfield{title} \clearfield{language}}
\addbibresource{demo.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Demo}
  \begin{block}{Text}
    I want to disable the language field in bibitems\cite{Kubota2007_JoCMD.14.367}\cite{Stukowski2012_MaSiMSaE.20.45021}.
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The final pdf file is also shown here.

[image: final pdf file shown as a picture]

The bib file is generated in JabRef. Could anybody tell me how to turnoff the `language` field?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 14):

If you look in the generated `.bbl` you can see that the language has this format:

```
\list{language}{1}{%
  {English}%
}
```

This means that it is a list, and so you must use `\clearlist{language}` to remove it.

Comment: That works! Really thank you very much for your help!