# Modifying `trad-alpha` to remove year from the bibliography item

Tags: biblatex

I have this minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{chapterref.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  shortdesc,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{shortdesc}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backref, refsegment=chapter, datamodel=chapterref, 
style=trad-alpha % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69706/38244
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author    = {Author, A. and Duthor, D.},
  year      = {2001},
  title     = {Alpha},
  shortdesc = {Conference1},
}


@misc{N02,
    author = {Nuthor, C.},
    title = {New title},
    year = {2001},
}

@misc{N03,
    author = {Nuthor, C},
    title = {More new title},
    year = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
  \chapter{First Chapter}
  Some more text \cite{A01}. More citation \cite{N02} and again \cite{N03}


  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It produces:

[image: cite-year]

and

[image: bib-year]

What I am looking for is to remove the years from the bibliography items (highlighted in yellow) together with the immediate comma before, while keeping the rest as it are. The year is kind of redundant (as the year is already mentioned in the cite item {luckiliy, I don't have to cite any paper more than 100 years old}).

Any advice will be appreciated.

**EDIT.**
As explained by @AlanMunn's comments, the [linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303385/biblatex-remove-year-labels) is significantly different. In that case, the other person asked for removing the duplicate year (which are suffixed by `a`, `b` etc.). In my case, I would like to remove the year from the bibliography key.

**EDIT 2.** (Also commented by @AlanMunn) I am still getting the same result as before with the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303387/38244) of the linked question.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, although the method is similar. For this question you need `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{year}}`. The linked question is getting rid of the *a*, *b* etc used in articles by the same author with the same year.

Comment: @Marijn So did I. The linked answer only deletes `extrayear` (now called `extradate` so nothing should happen anyway) and there isn't any `extradate`/`extrayear` here to begin with. Things might work if you delete the `year` field, but then that's slightly different.

Comment: @Marijn No, even if the solution is similar the question really is completely different. And questions should be closed based on the question, not on the similarity of answers.

Comment: I'm not sure why you've added the extra example. Both @moewe and I have pointed out that it doesn't do what you want. And the moewe's answer here *does* do what you want (as would the answer I gave in my comment.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Alright, I'll remove it. I saw Marijn's comment that "yes it does, I tried it myself :)", so I was confused whether I was missing something.

Comment: @pushpen.paul I'll try to explain a bit. The other question asked how to remove an element from the bibliography items, and so did your question. The answer to that other question was to use `\clearfield{that element}` and also for your question this is a solution. That is why I voted as duplicate, after I tried it myself and verified that the solution indeed works on your MWE. The difference is that 1. the element is different and 2. the element in the other question is automatically generated (the a, b suffix) and this one is not. So the thing you were missing is that you needed to change

Comment: the element from `extrayear` to `year`, which was readily identified by the comment of @AlanMunn.

Comment: @Marijn OK, I got it... Still, both the questions are different, regardless of how close the solutions are... I mean, for a novice like me, it's next to impossible to figure out the other solution (with a tweak) may work in my case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the bibliography macro `date` to print nothing. This is the method used by the `authoryear` standard styles to avoid printing the year twice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=trad-alpha]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  Some more text \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography without date]

---

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{year}}
```

as mentioned in the comments by Alan Munn and Marijn should also work here.

Note that `\AtEveryBibitem` will not suppress the year in a `\fullcite` citation, so there you would need

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{year}}
```

as well.

I usually prefer to use `\clearfield` only as a last resort and prefer source mapping (where the data is not even used by Biber, this is not an option here) or clearing the field with an input handler. A more detailed comparison of the several ways to suppress fields can be found in [How to omit address field while using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/491887/35864), [Remove title in biblatex references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141822/35864).

In this case I found it natural to simply redefine the bibmacro that would print the date to do nothing, since this is what the `authoryear` styles do in a similar situation, but this might not always be easily possible. If the styles had been different one might have had to redefine several different macros, at which point a different solution might have become more attractive.

Comment: What's the advantage of this over `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{year}}`?

Comment: @AlanMunn A matter of taste I would say. I prefer this method, because that's what the standard `authoryear` styles do in a (remotely) similar situation. Plus, I prefer to use `\clearfield` only when it can't be avoided (usually I think `\DeclareSourcemap` is nicer). `\clearfield{year}` might have the advantage that the year really is gone, but with `biblatex-trad` that is more of a theoretical issue...

Comment: When using `\fullcite` it might be preferred not to remove the year at every cite key, the reason to remove the year is to avoid redundancy of the year information in the key and in the entry itself, but in a `\fullcite` the key is not printed. That would also be an argument to prefer `\clearfield` over renewing `date`, i.e., to preserve `\fullcite` output.