# Remove space from author name in citation

Tags: bibliographies, biber

Consider the minimal working example (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494748/modifying-trad-alpha-to-remove-year-from-the-bibliography-item)):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{chapterref.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  shortdesc,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{shortdesc}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backref, refsegment=chapter, datamodel=chapterref, 
style=trad-alpha, % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69706/38244
minalphanames=3,maxalphanames=3 %https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-trad/issues/22
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author    = {Author, A. and Duthor, D.},
  year      = {2001},
  title     = {Alpha},
  shortdesc = {Conference1},
}


@misc{N02,
    author = {Nuthor, C.},
    title = {New title},
    year = {2001},
}

@misc{N03,
    author = {Nuthor, C},
    title = {More new title},
    year = {2000},
}

@misc{badum,
    author = {ba  Du  Tssh},
    title = {No new title},
    year = {2010},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
  \chapter{First Chapter}
  Some more text \cite{A01}. More citation \cite{N02} and again \cite{N03}

    Here is Ba-dum-tssh \cite{badum}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The problem I could not solve can be seen from the image:

[image]

Basically, there is an extra space between the author name's 3 characters and the year (possibly as the author name contains two spaces?). I want to get rid of the extra space, like this *[bDu10]*.

Comment: It's based on regular expressions, e.g., adding `\s{}` to the default `nolabel` definition (biblatex manual p 219) `\DeclareNolabel{
% strip punctuation, symbols, separator and control characters
\nolabel{\regexp{[\p{P}\p{S}\p{C}\s{}]+}}` gives `[DuT10]`.