# Biblatex appends letters to the year if the author is not unique

Tags: biblatex

I am currently writing a thesis where I use two different articles from the same author from the same year. As a result when using footnotes it appends a letter to the year, e.g. 2008a, 2008b, 2008c and so on. I don't need that nor am I allowed to do so judging from the guidelines I received.

I fail to understand why this is happening and what my steps would be to remove it completely. I read about a "uniquename" flag in the documentation but that seems to be for a different kind of issue.

I am importing biblatex like this (which is the standard way afaik): https://github.com/andygrunwald/FOM-LaTeX-Template/blob/master/thesis_main.tex#L120

Anyone got any input for me where I should start to get rid of this? Thanks a lot.

My example:

Import of biblatex and configuration

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=ext-authoryear,
maxcitenames=3,
maxbibnames=999,
mergedate=false,
date=iso,
seconds=true,
urldate=iso,
innamebeforetitle,
dashed=false,
autocite=footnote,
doi=false,
useprefix=true,
mincrossrefs = 1
]{biblatex}
```

I used the following sources as examples:

```
@online{example-1,
    usera = {Example One},
    title = {Example One},
    author = {Good Author},
    organization = {},
    location = {},
    date = {2018-12-20},
    urldate = {2019-01-02},
    urltime = {23:30},
    url = {https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/fullrefman.pdf},
}

@online{example-2,
    usera = {Example Two},
    title = {Example Two},
    author = {Good Author},
    organization = {},
    location = {},
    date = {2018-12-20},
    urldate = {2019-01-02},
    urltime = {23:30},
    url = {https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/fullrefman.pdf},
}
```

And made a citation like this:

```
Example citations here.\footcite[][]{example-1} \footcite[][]{example-2}
```

This results in:

> Author 2018a 
>   Author 2018b

I would like to get rid of the additional letters (a and b).

[Source code](https://github.com/thesiswriter1/mwe-latex/)

Comment: and how would you differentiate the articles if they are all cited as "author (2008)"? Adding a letter is the standard way here, and imho every guideline allows it.

Comment: Then check the documentation for extrayear (as you didn't provide a minimal example, I won't search myself)

Comment: A possible solution is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303385/35864. **But** there is probably a better way to do this. Unfortunately, I can only suggest a better way once I see what you are doing and how you are producing citations in a short example document (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: Please try to **minimise** the example so far that you can post it here directly in the question. Ideally the example would only consist of one file.

Comment: Is that code for the FOM(?) style and does it come from golatex?

Comment: @moewe the code itself is meant to be used for the FOM but I made some stylistic changes so it fits my university needs. I found it through GitHub. I digged through the configuration and I found no configuration which explicitly enables nor disables it. The documentation shows different configuration parameters: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf  --- the documentation explains when it's being used and how it's making use of mknumalph. However, I found no toggle for it

Comment: I changed my example so it only holds the bare minimum: https://github.com/thesiswriter1/mwe-latex - I'll also add it to my starting post.

Answer (score 3):

In the usual `authoryear` setting it makes no sense to remove the `extradate` information, indeed it can make your bibliography unusable because a reader has no way to match the citation to the bibliography entry. (There is no nice interface to turn off the `extradate` features in `authoryear` without turning off other features as well. But there is a not so nice way to achieve the result: [BibLaTeX – Remove Year Labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303385/35864). I should stress again that this is a *bad* idea.)

In your style you add a short title (in `usera`) to each citation, so that it becomes possible to distinguish two works by the same authors from the same year. You'll need the `extradate` only if there are two works from the same authors in the same year with the same `usera` field. I suggest that is what you request from `biblatex` with

```
\DeclareExtradate{%
  \scope{
    \field{labelyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \scope{
    \field{usera}
  }
}
```

Then the following reduced form of the original example

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  maxcitenames=3,
  maxbibnames=999,
  mergedate=false,
  date=iso,
  seconds=true,
  urldate=iso,
  urldateusetime=true,
  innamebeforetitle,
  dashed=false,
  autocite=footnote,
  doi=false,
  eprint=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=false,
  useprefix=true,
  mincrossrefs=1,
]{biblatex}



\DeclareExtradate{%
  \scope{
    \field{labelyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \scope{
    \field{usera}
  }
}


\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \printfield{usera}%
    \setunit{\printdelim{titleyeardelim}}%
    \ifentrytype{online}
       {\setunit*{\addspace\addcomma\addspace}%
         \iffieldundef{year}
           {\bibstring{nodate}}
           {\printlabeldateextra}}%
       {\printlabeldateextra}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
    \ifentrytype{online}
       {\setunit*{\addspace\addcomma\addspace}%
         \iffieldundef{year}
           {\bibstring{nodate}}
           {\printlabeldateextra}}%
       {\printlabeldateextra}}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nonameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
      {\toggletrue{abx@bool@giveninits}%
        \printnames[family-given]{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
      \printfield{usera}%
      \setunit{\printdelim{titleyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
   {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
}
@online{example-1,
  usera   = {Example One},
  title   = {Example One},
  author  = {Good Author},
  date    = {2018-12-20},
  urldate = {2019-01-02},
  urltime = {23:30},
  url     = {https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/fullrefman.pdf},
}
@online{example-2,
  usera   = {Example Two},
  title   = {Example Two},
  author  = {Good Author},
  date    = {2018-12-20},
  urldate = {2019-01-02},
  urltime = {23:30},
  url     = {https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/fullrefman.pdf},
}
@online{example-3,
  usera   = {Example Two},
  title   = {Example Two},
  author  = {Good Author},
  date    = {2018-12-20},
  urldate = {2019-01-02T23:30:00},
  url     = {https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/fullrefman.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem\footcite[][]{example-1}
ipsum\footcite[][]{example-2,example-3}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Author, G., Example One, 2018.//Author, G., Example Two, 2018a; Author, G., Example Two, 2018b.]

Note that the second footnote contains the disambiguation letters only because author, `usera` and year are the same.

Comment: @youngStupidQuestionGod Well, the FOM style is *very* peculiar. You can read the history of how (parts of) it came about at https://golatex.de/eigener-zitierstil-anpassung-authoryear-icomp-t20497.html and https://golatex.de/literaturverzeichnis-anpassung-t21484.html (in German, but I trust you read German; not everything in the FOM template comes from the linked discussions). If you don't need to follow FOM guidelines I strongly suggest you start from a different basis. There are many questions about `biblatex` customisations here and elsewhere ...

Comment: ... but I couldn't find a good answer for "author-title-year" footnotes just now and of course the best solution depends on your exact requirements. So I suggest you ask a new question. Please note that questions on TeX.SX should ideally be about a single issue only (and questions like "how do I write this style" with 30-odd requirements usually don't fit into that category). In that case a normal forum like https://golatex.de/ might be more suitable for the discussions that invariable have to take place.

Comment: Thanks, I will do so. Staying on the current question: I'm super grateful for all your help but I am still confused: The result still shows the letters being appended to the year, doesn't it?

Comment: @youngStupidQuestionGod Yes, but only if author, year *and* `usera` are the same. Not if only author and year are the same (otherwise footnote 1 would also have a letter). If there were no letter in the second footnote you could not distinguish the two citations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103212/discussion-between-youngstupidquestiongod-and-moewe).

Answer (score 1):

You can personalize the citation using a newcommand to simplify your task:

Supposing you just setted up the bibLaTeX, and author's name, title and year are separeted by single hyphens:

\newcommand{\citeG}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}-\citetitle{#1}-\citeyear{#1}}

Now you after this command you can use \citeG{bibkey} to cite the document according to your desired standard.

The lack of MWE (Minimal Working Example) makes a more effective response impossible, as Ulrike Fischer mentioned.

Comment: In general it is a really bad idea to combine several `\cite...` macros into a new command with `\newcommand`. Commands defined like this can usually not deal with citation of multiple works as expected (try `\citeG{sigfridsson,nussbaum}`). Additionally, some work is needed to make commands like this work with pre- and postnotes (`\citeG[see][86]{sigfridsson}`). Finally, with some styles commands like this may mess with the citation tracking feature in ways that are unexpected.